What are the integer solutions to $2x^5+3y^5=5z^5$?
This equation has the obvious integer solution $(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$. By Faltings's theorem, the equation has finitely many primitive integer solutions (those with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$).
What is the complete set of non-trivial primitive integer solutions (those with $\gcd(x,y,z)=1$
and $xyz≠0$) to this equation?
This is the equation of the form
$$
ax^5+by^5=cz^5,
$$
where $a,b,c$ are positive integer coefficients, with smallest value $a+b+c$ for which the problem of describing all integer solutions to the equation appears to be open.
The general equation can be reduced to the three hyperelliptic curves
$$
Y^2=-abX^5+c^2/4, \quad Y^2=acX^5+b^2/4, \quad Y^2=bcX^5+a^2/4.
$$
If one of these curves has rank of Jacobian $r \leq 1$, then the question is easy. Triple $(a,b,c)=(2,3,5)$ is the smallest triple for which the three hyperelliptic curves have rank of Jacobian $r \geq 2$. In this case, the curves are
$$
Y^2=-24X^5+25, \quad Y^2=-40X^5+9,\quad Y^2=15X^5+1,
$$
which have an easy to find rational point, and the curves have rank of Jacobian $3$, $2$ and $2$, respectively. Also, the existence of the solution $(1,1,1)$ implies that the standard version of the Mordell-Weil sieve will give no contradiction modulo any prime.
The problem of whether an integer solution exists to the general equation with $a+b+c<22$ has been solved in [1] but the problem for describing all integer solutions was not investigated.
[1] B. Grechuk. Polynomial Diophantine Equations: A Systematic Approach. Springer International Publishing, 2024. URL https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rj8eEQAAQBAJ.

I believe the case ``rank = genus" can now be handled by the Chabauty-Kim method, especially for hyperelliptic curves.

This is extremely interesting!

Stanley Yao Xiao, for rank 1 there is an implemetation in Magma. Is there any implementation for rank 2 genus 2 curves? Or at least a theorem that under some conditions (that can be checked in Magma) the rational points can be computed in finite time?

I don't think that rank = genus can be handled in general. The condition given in this paper that ensures the finiteness of the quadratic Chabauty set is ${\rm rank} < {\rm genus} + {\rm Picard~Number} - 1$. Because these genus $2$ curves have extra endomorphisms, their Picard rank over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is higher than $1$, but I'm pretty sure that's not true over $\mathbb{Q}$.
